# Não consigo usar um Subject do rxjs dentro do subscribe de uma conexão websocket com sockjs e stompjs, utilizando Angular 16

Tags: javascript, angular, front-end, websocket, rxjs

Olá, eu criei uma classe se serviço para websocket em minha aplicação de chat utilizando Angular 16. O método de conectar utilizando sockjs e stompjs funcionam normalmente, a conexão com meu servidor é estabelecida, e recebo as mensagens do mesmo normalmente. No entanto, quero emitir para outros componentes a mensagem recebida. Para isso utilizo um Subject do rxjs, que está em outra classe de serviço. Mas quanto tento emitir o evento, recebo um erro. Não faço ideia de como resolver, não existe nada sobre na web.

**Classe de serviço WEBSOCKET**

```
export class WebsocketService {
  private stompClient: any;

  constructor(private readonly mensagemSubjectsService: MensagemSubjectsService) { }

  public conectar(idUsuario: number): void {
    const endpointWS = `${environment.apiUrl}/chat`
    const socket = new SockJS(endpointWS);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const canalUsuario = `/topic/usuario/${idUsuario}`;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(canalUsuario, this.mensagemRecebida, this.erroOcorrido)
    })
  }

  private mensagemRecebida(resposta: any): void {
    const mensagemWS: MensagemWS = JSON.parse(resposta.body) as MensagemWS;
    if(mensagemWS.tipo == TipoMensagemWS.MENSAGEM_RECEBIDA) {
      this.mensagemSubjectsService.emitirEventoMensagemRecebida(resposta.body);
    }
  }

  private erroOcorrido(error: any): void {
    console.log('erro websocket');
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**Classe de serviço Subject**

```
export class MensagemSubjectsService {
  private _mensagemEnviada$: Subject<Mensagem> = new Subject();
  private _mensagemRecebida$ = new Subject<Mensagem>();

  public get mensagemEnviada$(): Subject<Mensagem> {
    return this._mensagemEnviada$;
  }

  public emitirEventoMensagemEnviada(mensagem: Mensagem): void {
    this._mensagemEnviada$.next(mensagem);
  }

  public emitirEventoMensagemRecebida(mensagem: Mensagem) {
    this._mensagemRecebida$.next(mensagem);
  }
  public get mensagemRecebida$(): Subject<Mensagem> {
    return this._mensagemRecebida$;
  }
}
```

**Erro**
[Imagem do erro no console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD5on.png)

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que por algum motivo, o método subscribe do stompClient não funciona muito bem com callbacks.

**Maneira que funciona**

```
public conectar(idUsuario: number): void {
    const endpointWS = `${environment.apiUrl}/chat`;
    const socket = new SockJS(endpointWS);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const canalUsuario = `/topic/usuario/${idUsuario}`;

    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(
        canalUsuario,
        (resposta: any) => {
          const mensagemWS: MensagemWS = JSON.parse(resposta.body) as MensagemWS;
          if (mensagemWS.tipo == TipoMensagemWS.MENSAGEM_RECEBIDA) {
            this.mensagemSubjectsService.emitirEventoMensagemRecebida(
              mensagemWS.mensagem
            );
          }
        },
        (erro: any) => {
          console.log(erro);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

**Código antigo, que não funcionou**

```
public conectar(idUsuario: number): void {
    const endpointWS = `${environment.apiUrl}/chat`
    const socket = new SockJS(endpointWS);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const canalUsuario = `/topic/usuario/${idUsuario}`;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(canalUsuario, this.mensagemRecebida, this.erroOcorrido)
    })
  }

  private mensagemRecebida(resposta: any): void {
    const mensagemWS: MensagemWS = JSON.parse(resposta.body) as MensagemWS;
    if(mensagemWS.tipo == TipoMensagemWS.MENSAGEM_RECEBIDA) {
      this.mensagemSubjectsService.emitirEventoMensagemRecebida(resposta.body);
    }
  }
```

Comment: O motivo da nova versão funcionar é que as arrow functions mantêm o `this` do contexto externo, ao contrário de funções anônimas normais. O código antigo funcionaria se você utilizasse `bind` para criar funções vinculadas ao objeto desejado, e passá-las ao subcribe.